# Events only fire first time

Tags: xforms, episerver

I have an episite with an xForm that i am trying to manipulate before it is submitted. Im trying to get the formdata att the global.asax like this:

```
public void XFormControlSetup(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {       
        control.BeforeLoadingForm += XFormBeforeLoadingForm;
        control.ControlsCreated += XFormControlsCreated;
        control.BeforeSubmitPostedData += XFormBeforeSubmitPostedData;
        control.AfterSubmitPostedData += XFormAfterSubmitPostedData;
    }
```

First time i debug XFormControlSetup fires and sets the eventhandlers. The events fire. But only the first time i submit the form! After this the evnts wont fire even if i restart the debugging.

Comment: i solved it. The events ARE triggered. Its Visual Studios debug that does not always break at the breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

i solved it. The events ARE triggered. Its Visual Studios debug that does not always break at the breakpoints